# Filter list using dynamic query?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, filter

I am trying to filter a list of objects of type Proxy.  Here are it's properties.

```
Public Property IP As String
Public Property Port As Integer
Public Property Status As ProxyStatus
Public Property Country As String
Public Property Speed As Integer
```

On the filter form, I have a CheckListBox with country names, and if a country is checked it should be included in the filtered results.

I know I can use hardcoded LINQ likeso:

```
Dim result = proxies.Where(Function(p) p.Country = "USA" OR p.Country = 
     "Russia")
```

But since my query is dynamic, depending on which countries are checked on the user form, how can I go about this when there are say, 50 countries that I want to include in my results?  I've read about PredicateBuilder but I haven't found an example that includes logical OR's, like if I am filtering by the Status property and I want to include proxies whose Status = Valid OR Status = Unknown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a collection and `Contains`:

```
Dim countries As String() = SelectedCountries
Dim result = proxies.Where(Function(p) countries.Contains(p.Country))
```

I have used `SelectedCountries` since i don't know how the user can select the countries. But i'm sure you know to create that array(or list).

Furthermore:

> I need a dynamic OR statement, for example Status = Valid OR Status =
>   Unknown. This being dependent on the users selection of various
>   checkboxes

```
Dim allowedStatuses = SelectedStatuses
result = result.Where(Function(p) allowedStatuses.Contains(p.Status))
```

You note that i use `result = result.Where` not `proxies.Where`. You can concat multiple `Where`, which is similar as using `OrElse` in the first `Where`. In my opinion this is more readable here.

Comment: Hi, thanks Tim.  That solves part of my question for sure, thanks for that.  How about in the case where I need a dynamic OR statement, for example Status = Valid OR Status = Unknown.  This being dependent on the users selection of various checkboxes on the filtering form.  If you can help me with that last part of my question I will surely mark this as the answer.

Comment: @DavidStampher:have a look

Comment: @TimSchemlter Exactly what I was looking for yeah.  Thanks a ton. (27 seconds and I can mark as answer...)